# Django TemplateDoesNotExist error - wrong path to templates folder

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am currently watching the Django lecture from CS50W and was coding along with Brian just fine. But now I keep getting the same error no matter what I do. I want to render the simple HTML5 page with Django and even though I have specified the correct path to the templates folder and index.html.
It goes to `hello/templates/` and tries to find `newyear/index.html` there.

```
from Django.shortcuts import render
from datetime import datetime


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    now = datetime.now()
    return render(request, 'newyear/index.html', {
        'newyear': now.month == 1 and now.day == 1
    })
```

And I get an error as stated below

```
Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 
/home/root/cs50w/week3-Django/lecture3/hello/templates/newyear/index.html 
(Source does not exist)

    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/newyear/index.html 
(Source does not exist)

    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/newyear/index.html 
(Source does not exist)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/root/cs50w/week3-Django/lecture3/newyear/views.py", line 8, in index
    return render(request, 'newyear/index.html', {
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /newyear/
Exception Value: newyear/index.html
```

Directory structure of the project

```
Lecture 3/
├── lecture3/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── hello/
│   ├── templates/
│   │   └── hello/
│   │       ├── greet.html
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── newyear/
│   ├── template/
│   │   └── newyear/
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── manage.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newyear your directory is called /template not /templates - add an 's' to the directory name and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I overlooked that.

Comment: did the question provide enough information, and was it written properly?

Comment: The question is fine, in my opinion, but the problem ended up being a typo so it's of limited use for others on the site and may end up being closed. This is just normal procedure and doesn't reflect badly on the asker.